# I have a geometrically more intuitive proof for Borsuk–Ulam theorem, but does it work?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Theorem 1.10 (The Borsuk-Ulam) in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology is

> For every continuous map $f:S^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ there exists a pair of antipodal points $x$ and $-x$ in $S^2$ with $f(x)=f(-x)$.

The proof given in that book is simple but I find the intuitive behind is not so clear. I have an intuitive idea that should lead to a proof, but I'm not sure it works. I want to argue as follows:

Suppose the conclusion is false, then we can define a map $g:D^2\to S^1$ as follows: for each point $(x,y)$ in the the disk $D^2$, there is a unique point $(x,y,z)$ in the upper hemisphere corresponding to it, then we define
$$g(x,y)=\frac{f(x,y,z)-f(-x,-y,-z)}{|f(x,y,z)-f(-x,-y,-z)|}.$$
The map $g$ is continuous and surjective, but this is impossible, a contradiction.

Comment: There are of course continuous surjections $D^2 \to S^1$.

Comment: thanks, I have found continuous surjections $D^2\to S^1$.